# Will this character become a Zombie?

Tags: the-walking-dead

Can someone explain whether, following his death, given that his brain and head are intact

> Tyrese

on The Walking Dead will turn into a zombie.

Comment: His head and brain may have been intact after being killed by the walker, but I would put money on Rick and the others putting a bullet through his brain before burying him.

Answer (score 10):

If you're referring to the TV series, then they didn't show it, but it's implied that they "took care of it".

Check out the scene where we see him finally die:

Around minute 5:12, Michone draws her sword, and the scene changes to him being buried... he's dead, brain's cut, he's not coming back.

Just to add another reason, they would never leave him there to raise as a zombie, not to him and not to anyone from their group, that would be like desecrating the grave or the corpse, it's part of the burial process now in that world, if your loved one dies, you stick a pointy object into his/her head.

Comment: Kinda like when you live in a world infested by vampires, you always decapitate before burial. Or just cremate.

Comment: Indeed my friend, indeed